# analysis of dynamic programming Matrix-Chain-Order

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, matrix-multiplication

So we I have the Matrix chain order algorithm which finds the optimal way in multiplying matrices. I see why it would have a run time of O(n^3) but having trouble proving its big-Omega(n^3). The algorithm is below
Algorithm Matrix-Chain-Order(p)

```
1. n ← p.length − 1
2. for i ← 1 to n do
3.   m[i, i] ← 0
4. for l ← 2 to n do
5.    for i ← 1 to n − l + 1 do
6.      j ← i + l − 1
7.      m[i, j] ← ∞
8.      for k ← i to j − 1 do
9.        q ← m[i, k] + m[k + 1, j] + pi−1pkpj (these are P(base)i-1
10.       if q < m[i, j] then
11.         m[i, j] ← q
12.         s[i, j] ← k
13. return s
```

O(n^3) is obvious since there are three loops which are nested and run O(n) times. How would I go about finding big-Omega(n^3)

Comment: You really have a variable named backquote? and what's pi-1pkpj?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To better understand question one could look [here](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ads/Lects/DP.pdf).

You need to compute elements of upper tirangular matrix. Let's look at these subdiagonals:

1. First subdiagonal, you need only **1** operation per its element, and the diagonal has **n-1** element.
2. Second subidagonal you need **2** ops and it has **n-2** elems.
   ...
3. For the last subdiagonal you need **n-1** ops and it has **1** elem.

So, you have a summation i(n-i), for 0 < i < n. This summation can be split in two parts:

- sum(in) = n(1+2+...(n-1)) = n(n/2)(n-1) = n^3/2-n^2/2
- sum(i^2) = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6 = n^3/3+n^2/2+n/6

Now subtract and you will have n^3/6+...

So, it is Omega(n^3).